# How to get Azure service pricing details programmatically?

Tags: azure

Can anybody please tell me how can I programmatically get Azure service pricing details (pricing for Compute, Data Services , App Services, Network Services) from Azure website?

Does Azure provide the pricing details in JSON format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Windows Azure does'not provide any such API as of today, although it is a much asked feature and hopefully they are working on it.

Check here:
http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/170030-billing/suggestions/1143971-billing-usage-api#comments

The only way for now could be to build your own data store with details mentioned here : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Unit wise price will be mentioned in the usage data csv, but unfortunately the only way for now is to download this csv for your subscription here: https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

Azure now provides API's to get usage and billing data. You can have a look at [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-overview/) which gives an overview of these API's and [the feedback form here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-billing/suggestions/1143971-billing-usage-api) which contains links to some useful pages.

In summary use the following API's to get usage and billing data:

- [Resource usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219003)
- [Resource ratecard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219005)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if i am too late to answer.

I was looking for the same thing and stumble upon this post on stack overflow: [Azure pricing calculator api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216539/azure-pricing-calculator-api). I was able to generate JSON string using this git hub repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I found myself looking for this and nothing here got me what I wanted. Then I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

It is pretty straight forward. Add the reference to the Json.NET .NET 4.0 to your project It shows up in your references as Newtonsoft.Json

```
    //You will need to add these usings

    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;

    private void btnGetRates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUrl = "https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and skuName eq 'E64 v4' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'";

        string response = GetDataFromAPI(strUrl);

        // Here is am turning the Json response into a datatable and then loading that into a DataGridView.
        //You can use the Json response any way you wish
        DataTable dt = Tabulate(response); 
        dgvAzureSKU.DataSource = null;
        dgvAzureSKU.DataSource = dt;
    }

    public string GetDataFromAPI(string url)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public static DataTable Tabulate(string json)
    {
        var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(json);

        // Find the first array using Linq
        var srcArray = jsonLinq.Descendants().Where(d => d is JArray).First();
        var trgArray = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject row in srcArray.Children<JObject>())
        {
            var cleanRow = new JObject();
            foreach (JProperty column in row.Properties())
            {
                if (column.Value is JValue) // Only include JValue types
                {
                    cleanRow.Add(column.Name, column.Value);
                }
            }
            trgArray.Add(cleanRow);
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(trgArray.ToString()); //This is what loads the data into the table
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples for that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview. Azure provides invoice, usage and ratecard APIs which can help you to do things like:

- Azure spend during the month
- Set up alerts
- Predict bill
- Pre-consumption cost analysis