# Pricing API for Azure

Tags: azure

Is there a pricing api for azure similar to what AWS has for product listing and pricing catalog.For example to get EC2 pricing and product catalog AWS gives a [JSON/CSV file](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json) , Wondering if there is anything similar for Azure

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview

Comment: Looks like this api is more for invoicing , it does not return a master product catalog

Comment: Usage and Rate Card API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/1ea5b323-54bb-423d-916f-190de96c6a3c. BTW, it is not same as AWS.

Comment: ..APIs provide access to resource consumption and metadata information for Azure subscriptions - This is very specific to a subscription.How can i find out for example a list of Azure VM's available in the us-east region with associated pricing information

Comment: Rate Card API will provide you that information. You would need to provide a billing plan though. That's why I said that it is different than AWS. IMHO, AWS API is very straight forward.

Comment: @muddassir If you want to get us-east region VM pricing information. I suggest you could use Azure pricing calculator.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Azure service pricing details programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511171/how-to-get-azure-service-pricing-details-programmatically)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Also, off-site resource requests are off-topic

Answer (score 3):

https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices

you can use query to read particular item like below

```
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=ArmRegionName%20eq%20%27eastus%27
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is trying to use PowerShell to call this API, here is a way of doing it.

I was getting `{"Error":{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Invalid OData parameters supplied"}}` because I was being stupid and not escaping the `$` in `$filter` with a backtick (`).

```
$Currency = "GBP"
$Region = "uksouth"
$EndpointUri = "https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?api-version=2021-10-01-preview&currencyCode=$Currency&`$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and ArmRegionName eq '$Region'"

$oRequest = $null
$oRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $EndpointUri -Method Get -Verbose
$oRequest
```

This will return something like:

```
BillingCurrency    : GBP
CustomerEntityId   : Default
CustomerEntityType : Retail
Items              : {@{currencyCode=GBP; tierMinimumUnits=0; retailPrice=0.4058; unitPrice=0.4058; armRegionName=uksouth; location=UK South;
                     effectiveStartDate=01/11/2021 00:00:00; meterId=001fa6ba-405f-5854-9dd5-5ecd8a7d7ef3; meterName=D48s v5 Low Priority;
                     productId=DZH318Z08M9T; skuId=DZH318Z08M9T/000W; productName=Virtual Machines Dsv5 Series Windows; skuName=Standard_D48s_v5 Low
                     Priority; serviceName=Virtual Machines; serviceId=DZH313Z7MMC8; serviceFamily=Compute; unitOfMeasure=1 Hour; type=DevTestConsumption;   
                     isPrimaryMeterRegion=True; armSkuName=Standard_D48s_v5}…}
NextPageLink       : https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?api-version=2021-10-01-preview&currencyCode=GBP&$filter=serviceName%20eq%20%27Virtual%20
                     Machines%27%20and%20ArmRegionName%20eq%20%27uksouth%27&$skip=100
Count              : 100
```

HTH.

Comment: Escaping the `$` in `$filter`, Ok that was the missing point for me too.

Comment: I would also suggest to check the [Query options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-overview) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

Example apis(you don't need an azure account to hit these apis)
"https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and priceType eq 'Reservation'"

"https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Storage'"

"https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Compute'"

"https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=endswith(armRegionName, 'europe')"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the consumption API Usage Details - List

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01
```

Here is the **[`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list)**.

if you want to see the usage details, use the api

[`Get Virtual Machine usage metrics using the REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/metrics-vm-usage-rest)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure Consumption [Price Sheet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/pricesheet/get):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/pricesheets/default?api-version=2019-10-01
```

Use the `expand` parameter, you will get a list of pricing looking like this:

```
{
    "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/20191001",
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "includedQuantity": "0",
    "meterDetails": {
        "meterCategory": "Virtual Machines",
        "meterLocation": "US East",
        "meterName": "D2s v3",
        "meterSubCategory": "Dv3 VDI Series Windows",
        "pretaxStandardRate": "None",
        "totalIncludedQuantity": "None",
        "unit": "10 Hours"
    },
    "meterId": "YYYYYY-YYYYY-YYYYYYYYYYY-YYYYYY",
    "partNumber": "AAD-3489577",
    "unitOfMeasure": "10 Hours",
    "unitPrice": "0.834958995845993200054867"
},
```

See also this stackoverflow question: [How to get Azure service pricing details programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511171/how-to-get-azure-service-pricing-details-programmatically).