# How can I get the cost of an Azure Resource group from the Azure api?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to get the cost of my VM from the Azure Api in c#. I'm pretty much able to get all the VM information but the cost its accumulated so far this month. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: We need a bit more information to be able to help you. What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want the costs accumulated, or not? And if not, what costs are you looking for? Does it need to be the total of everything connected to the VM? Or only the price of the VM sku/tier? What have you tried, and why didn't that work? Please refer to [ask].

Comment: I'd like to see the total accumulated cost for this period for the VM. I've tried both the billing api and consumption api with no luck. It could be that it is possible with either but I haven't been able to see this.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to see the total accumulated cost for this period for the VM

To check the accumulated cost for your VM you can use the [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?OCID=AID2200195_SEM_1cc029dba7841ccfb69648addb003d21:G:s&ef_id=1cc029dba7841ccfb69648addb003d21:G:s&msclkid=1cc029dba7841ccfb69648addb003d21) .

Below is the screenshot to check the cost of the vm for the day/month/Hour :

[image]

Still if you have any query/doubt you can reach out to  [Azure support](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview)

For more information please refer the below links:

SO THREAD:  [Pricing API for Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668285/pricing-api-for-azure)

MS DOC: [Azure Retail Prices API sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices)

Blog  [Analyze And Monitor Azure Spending](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/analyze-and-monitor-azure-spending/)