# Get historical data from Azure pricing API

Tags: python, azure, price

I would like to obtain historical pricing information for the azure virtual machine instances, using the Azure pricing API (or another tool I can use from within python - open to suggestions).

The pricing API is here: [Pricing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices)

And while there is an `effectiveStartDate` field, I can't seem to be able to use it to get pricing information for a specific date.

Does anyone know how to get historical Azure VM pricing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-filters)

We can not filter for a specific date to get the Price details but we can use the below to our API for  filter .
[image]

[image]

AFAIK, there is no such way to filter using start date or end date .

For more information please refer the below Links:-

- SO THREAD: [***Azure pricing APIs***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668285/pricing-api-for-azure/71020747#71020747)
- MS DOC:- [***Azure Spot Virtual Machines Pricing***](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/virtual-machines/spot/) & [***Pricing and eviction history for Azure VM***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/spot-vms#pricing)